# How can showing in my web, Facebook rating stars?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, web

Well, I have one website where i'm using the Facebook Plugin (the typical box with your followers and posts)...How i can showing the Facebook Rating in the same box? I'm not found the option :S

It's this possible?

Thanks for help me! And sorry for my English ;)

Edit:

Thanks for the URL's in i'm found one example and i'm editing this. I've the following code:

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/1447162575539510/ratings', function(response) {
    if (response && response.error){
        console.log("ERROR: "+response.error.message);
    }else{
        console.log("RESPONSE: "+response.open_graph_story);
    //console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.rating);
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ='Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    }
});
//FB.api("/410442505719113/ratings",function(response){
           //if (response && !response.error){
            //console.log(response.name);
           //}else{
            //console.log("ERROR : "+response.error.message);
           //}
        //});
  }
```

But always give me the same error: ERROR: (#210) Subject must be a page. And i don't know for why, the profile is a page in facebook

Comment: you would need to create an app for that and use the graph api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/ratings

Comment: thanks for the href @luschn but...i never used the graph api. Somebody can explain me? I'm not understood the documentation in facebook :S

Answer (score 0):

Here´s what you have to do:

- Create a Facebook App
- Authorize a page admin with the `manage_pages` permission
- Extend the User Access Token (from 2h to 60 days)
- User `/me/accounts` with that Token to get an Extended Page Access Token
- User `/{page-id}/ratings` with that Page Token to get the ratings

Some links for you, covering all those todos:

- https://developers.facebook.com/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/accounts
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/ratings
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for the url but...i'm try the code (I put the code in the question) but isn't works

Comment: Sorry, is too long to put in a comment, i edit the question with the code

Comment: there is no authorization, no generation of a page token, .... read my steps carefully, this is not just a few lines of code, you should know exactly what you do. that´s why i added all those important links too.

Comment: I found in your url's one example with javascript and i'm try to use...but i have the code error: ERROR: (#210) Subject must be a page. The profile it's a page type in facebook. Why can be the reason?

Comment: well, you probably did not use a page token

Comment: I don't know how can be generate or get the access_token with code..i'm not understand when i need use the GET /{user-id}/accounts and what is the user-id

Comment: then start reading the links i posted, they offer a lot of information that is needed for the task - how to handle access tokens, for example.